# How do I get my paper sent to the right editor?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, editors

Suppose I have found the perfect journal for my manuscript.  That journal has 50 editors.  Editor A is an expert in the subject of my manuscript.  What can I do to get my paper handled by Editor A, instead of one of the other editors?

Comment: Try emailing that editor and see if you can make arrangements - don’t include the paper with the first email.

Answer (score 8):

This is going to depend on how the journal is set up, but two suggestions:

1. Suggest in the cover letter that Editor A handle your manuscript.
2. When asked to classify your manuscript choose keywords that closely match Editor A's expertise. (You probably are doing this already anyway.)

Note that it's not a guarantee that Editor A handles your manuscript even if he/she is perfect for the role - it's conceivable Editor A is too busy, is on holiday, etc.

Comment: 1a. Suggest in the cover letter that Editor A would be a good reviewer for the manuscript (and hope the editorial assistant takes the hint).

Comment: For some journals you are even explicitly asked to suggest handling editors.

Comment: @Allure Please recently I submitted a paper to a math springer journal without a cover letter. Is this can make a problem?

Comment: @Student it potentially can but probably won't.

Comment: @Allure Thank you. I don't find where I attached it. In the future should I attach it as an attachment to the manuscript? The problem when I try to add it as an attachment to the manuscript, I find the cover letter in the last page of the manuscript.

Comment: @Student Conventions about cover letters seem to differ from one field to another. My cover "letters" in recent years have been email messages of the form "Dear [editor's name], I would like to submit the attached paper, [title of paper], for publication in [title of journal]. Sincerely yours, Andreas Blass" (where "Sincerely yours" may become "Best regards" and my last name may be omitted,  depending on how well I know the editor). The only attachment is a pdf file of the paper.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you very much. Can I also suggest the name of some reviewers?

Comment: @Student Yes, you can suggest reviewers, but of course it's entirely up to the editor whether to pay any attention to your suggestions.